# NO_SUCHFILE ...\u2net.onnx .u2net\u2net.onnx failed. File doesn't exist , rembg

Tags: python, python-3.x, rembg

```
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image
input_path = 'input.png'
output_path = 'output.png'
input = Image.open(input_path)
output = remove(input)
output.save(output_path)
```

I get an error

```
sess = C.InferenceSession(session_options, self._model_path, True, self._read_config_from_model)
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.NoSuchFile: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 3 : NO_SUCHFILE : Load model from C:\Users\User\.u2net\u2net.onnx failed:Load model C:\Users\User\.u2net\u2net.onnx failed. File doesn't exist
```

I can't figure out what's wrong, I checked everything

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/issues/318

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/releases/download/v0.0.0/u2net.onnx

Make sure that after the download is completed, copy U2Net.onnx to C: \ Users \ <your username> . u2net \ this folder
Then reopen the code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34840753)